# Invalid Reference Format - SQL Server Image

Tags: docker

I have been scratching my head for the past hour trying to figure out what is wrong with this docker run command. It keeps giving me a `docker: invalid reference format.` error. But it looks all good to me. Can someone maybe point out what's wrong:

```
docker run --detach \
    --name sqlserver-db \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    -u 0:0 \
    -p 3341:1433 \
    -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" \
    -e "SA_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
    -e "MSSQL_PID=Standard" \
    -v /var/lib/docker/containers/sqlserver/data:/var/opt/mssql/data \
    -v /var/lib/docker/containers/sqlserver/log:/var/opt/mssql/log \
    -v /var/lib/docker/containers/sqlserver/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets \
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU4-ubuntu-18.04
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does `SA_PASSWORD` contains any special characters or it's just an alphanumeric string?

Comment: It's just an alphanumeric string.

Comment: I tried this similar command ( removed the volume mounts ) and was able to run it successfully. As a debug approach, I would recommend you to first run the container without any options. `docker run -itd --name  sqlserver-db mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU4-ubuntu-18.04` If this executes without any error, then add options one by one. Maybe you could pinpoint the exact option that is causing the issue. Btw, which docker version are you using? and which OS?

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal - I typed it out manually for the umpteenth time and it worked. No idea what the issue was, but typing it out manually in notepad++ did the trick

Answer (score 0):

For anybody running into this issue where the docker run command doesn't want to work even though the syntax looks correct; type the command out manually in Notepad++ and it should do the trick.